# Как узнать,что запущена именно UI?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть CL(command line) приложение, в качестве формы выводится форма для настроек. Так вот, при попытке вызвать второй раз форму отображается сообщение "мол, форма запущена".При другом раскладе, когда переданы данные и запускается процесс - нужно мне сделать так, чтобы можно было запускать не один процесс а несколько. Объяснил как мог. Можно ли как-то узнать -запущена именно UI или нет. Может, можно процессу назначить какой-то уникальный ID?

Comment: Я когда то делал функционал, который должен был запретить запуск второго интсанса приложения, если первый ещё запущен. Я тогда юзал [мьютексы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), может вам что то типа того же надо.

Comment: Ещё [немного инфы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567)

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Да, я использовал Mutex для реализации запрета. Но мне нужно как-то определить запущена именно форма или нет.

Comment: При запуске формы - захватывайте мьютекс, при уничтожении - освобождайте. Какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: Открыл форму, захватил мутекс, форма не закрыта и я подаю из командной строки входные параметры и запускаю процесс еще раз - в этом случае выполняется обработка данных, но форма пользователя отображаться не будет. Вот в этом проблема.

Comment: форма может быть открыта только один раз, но при открытой форме или закрытой количество процессов может выполняться более чем один

Comment: `но форма пользователя отображаться не будет. Вот в этом проблема.` Так вам надо, чтобы форма показалась или НЕ показалась? Я не понял этого

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь. Это Winforms приложение, я использую как commond line приложение, т.е. если есть входные данные, то выполняется, к примеру, удаление файлов. Если входных данных нет, то запускается форма, на которой пользователь может установить настройки для удаления. Форма может запуститься только один раз и это я проверяю, но вот запуск процесса на удаление может запускаться паралельно несколько раз. к примеру, запущен процесс на удаление файлов в папке "del с:\1", не дожидаеясь выполнения можно запустить "del с:\2". На данном этапе,

Comment: Тк. я проверяю запущен ли процесс я не могу параллельно запустить несколько процессов. Если уберу проверку, то все будет работать. Но в этом случае форма с настройками может быть запущена несколько раз

Comment: поэтому я и хочу знать, запущена ли форма с настройками - в этом случае при попытке запустить ее еще раз будет выведено сообщение.

Comment: в кратце, сейчас с проверкой на наличие процесса я могу запустить только один процесс на удаление, потом дождаться и запустить другой... Именно форму нельзя запускать повторно

Comment: `с проверкой на наличие процесса` - так проверяйте не наличие процесса, а наличие формы. Какие с этим проблемы? Берите проверку наличия процесса по ссылке, что я вам дал, но адаптируйте её для себя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмем класс из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810107/312041)

```
    class SingleGlobalInstance : IDisposable
    {
        //edit by user "jitbit" - renamed private fields to "_"
        public bool _hasHandle = false;
        Mutex _mutex;

        private void InitMutex()
        {
            string appGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false).GetValue(0)).Value;
            string mutexId = string.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", appGuid);
            _mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexId);

            var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            var securitySettings = new MutexSecurity();
            securitySettings.AddAccessRule(allowEveryoneRule);
            _mutex.SetAccessControl(securitySettings);
        }

        public SingleGlobalInstance(int timeOut)
        {
            InitMutex();
            try
            {
                if (timeOut < 0)
                    _hasHandle = _mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite, false);
                else
                    _hasHandle = _mutex.WaitOne(timeOut, false);

                if (_hasHandle == false)
                    throw new TimeoutException("Timeout waiting for exclusive access on SingleInstance");
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException)
            {
                _hasHandle = true;
            }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_mutex != null)
            {
                if (_hasHandle)
                    _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                _mutex.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Но вызывать его будем только в том случае, если наша программа запущена без параметров. Вообще наше консольное приложение эмулирует какую то работу если ему передают параметры (не важно какие) или открывает форму если его вызвали без параметров. При открытии формы идет попытка захватить мьютекс, если попытка не удалась - то мьютекс уже захвачен и прекращаем работу. таким образом простая работа может быть запущена сколько угодно раз, окно настроек - только 1 инстанс одновременно

Код:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args?.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleting files in progress: {i}%");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                using (var mutex = new SingleGlobalInstance(0))
                {
                    var wnd = new Window();
                    wnd.Title = "Settings";
                    wnd.Content = new Label() {Content = "I am settings window"};
                    wnd.Width = 300;
                    wnd.Height = 300;
                    wnd.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                    wnd.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Settings window already opened!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: спасибо огромное - то ,что нужно